# Xamarin.Facebook.Android failing to install

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to install the Xamarin.Facebook.Android SDK for Client Flow Facebook login but when I go to install the package the Package Manager does the following:

`Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Xamarin.Facebook.Android.4.22.0' with respect to project 'NapChat.Droid', targeting 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Xamarin.Facebook.Android.4.22.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Xamarin.Facebook.Android.4.22.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'Xamarin.Facebook.Android.4.22.0'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Xamarin.Facebook.Android.4.22.0' does not exist in project 'NapChat.Droid'
Package 'Xamarin.Facebook.Android.4.22.0' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\NCHAT\NapChat\packages'
Could not install package 'Xamarin.Facebook.Android 4.22.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
========== Finished ==========`

How do I fix this to install the Facebook SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error log,your current Mono.Android is of version 6.0, which doesn't meet the requirement of Facebook SDK 4.22.0:

[image]

So, it is highly recommended to install the latest Xamarin.Android through VS installer or from the [download page](https://www.xamarin.com/download-it?_bt=101035044668&_bk=xamarin&_bm=e&gclid=Cj0KEQjwyZjKBRDu--WG9ayT_ZEBEiQApZBFuNG8sKc0nyEkasWdnhaAk9Q29oDCG36dhV0MXRJ7qk8aAo3k8P8HAQ).

Or, you can install Xamarin.Facebook.Android of version 4.16.1, which targets the min version of Mono.Android 4.0.3.

Comment: I'm having troubles on how to update the Xamarin.Android. I went to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Options and clicked Check Now and updated Xamarin but my Xamarin.Android is still not v7.0

Comment: Please try download the Android 7.0 SDK through Android SDK Manager. And config the project to use Android 7.0 compiler. If it still doesn't work. Please try uninstall the Xamarin first and reinstall it freshly.